# Pick a random square and generate a random number

Tags: c++, c, random

I have an board 4 x 4 (16 squares have value 0). I have to pick a random square in this board and generate a random value for this square.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/time.h>

using namespace std;

void pickSquare(int [][4]);
void printSquare(int [][4]);

int main() {
    int a[4][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            a[i][j] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << i << endl;
        pickSquare(a);
        printSquare(a);
    }
}

void pickSquare(int a[][4]) {
    struct timeval t1;
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    srand(t1.tv_usec * t1.tv_sec);

    int randValue = rand() % 10;
    if (randValue == 0 || randValue == 1) randValue = 4;
    else randValue = 2;

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            if (a[i][j] == 0) ++count;
    int random = rand() % count;

    cout << endl << "count = " << count;
    cout << endl << "random = " << random;


    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            if (a[i][j] == 0) {
                if (count == random) {
                    a[i][j] = randValue;
                    cout << endl << "  " << i << "  " << j << endl;
                    break;
                }
                ++count;
            }       
        if (count == random) break;
    }
}

void printSquare(int a[][4]) {
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << "  ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Function `pickSquare(int [][4])` is used to pick a random Square and generate a random value. 
Function `printSquare(int [][4])` is used to print the board 4 x 4.

I think everything is fine but when I run my program, sometimes the program doesn't pick any square. Therefore after completing the function, the board is still the same.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Maybe you want to use `srand(NULL)` inside `main()`, not inside the called function.

Comment: I tried but the problem is that you would get the same answer almost every time

Comment: probably because of `if (randValue == 0 || randValue == 1) randValue = 4;
    else randValue = 2;`

Comment: I think the problem is not about the random function. It is about why sometimes the program doesn't pick any square although everything seems to be correct.

Comment: seed `srand()` only once. use `rand()` many times.

Comment: *"sometimes the program doesn't pick any square"* - you should include the cout output from a run where the program didn't pick any square.

Comment: `if (count == random)`....what if not?

Comment: if count != random then the function still move on

Comment: I'm confused, if you're looking to deal with 4*4 (16) elements, why do you why are you looping and checking if the random number matches? It should be really simple. Given something like `number = random() % 16`, you can access board item `a[number / 4][number % 4]` immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the

```
if (count == random) break;
```

Here you can break out for an untested count when the inner loop completes.

Comment: @Pea Nguyen: Consider a case with random being 1 and the first row have the first 3 squares occupied and the the last square empty. What will happen when the inner loop completes....

Comment: @Pea Nguyen: BTW - I think your code would be more readable if you added more {...}. For instance it is a bit difficult to see exactly which code is included in the inner loop. However, it is just a matter of style so perhaps I should not comment on this....

Comment: Yeah, I added '{' in the same line, not in a new line. I think people can still read and understand my code. I agree it is just a matter of style.